# Should non-citizens pay gift tax for sending bitcoin to non-citizen living abroad?

Tags: taxes, transfer, cryptocurrency

I am non-us citizen (an international student) but resident alien for tax purposes. If I send my bitcoins to my family living abroad, should I pay the gift tax? I read articles but they say 'us citizens must pay the gift tax if the amount exceeds $14,000 per year'.

Comment: To how many relatives?

Comment: does your gift exceed $14,000?

Comment: combining two above questions, does your gift exceed $14,000 _per recipient_ ?

Comment: "I am non-us citizen (an international student) but resident alien for tax purposes." Are you sure? An international student will generally only be a resident alien for a given year if they have been an international student in the US for some part of 5 previous calendar years.

Comment: Okay. First, the gift exceeds $14,000 per recipient. My questions is regardless of the citizenship, the gift tax applies to everyone in the US??

Comment: And I am non-US citizen and resident alien. I have been in the US for 5 previous calendar years.